# 404 Page not loading after .net 4 upgrade

Tags: .net, iis, http-status-code-404, sitecore

I have an issue where my 404 pages are not loading in our CMS, I realied it came to one line in the code on those 404 pages.

I.e.
Response.StatusCode = 0x194

So when I load the 404 I get the old school 404 pages

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

What I want instead is actual content of 404 pages from my cms to display. So I figure it's something to do with this line.

Response.StatusCode = 0x194;

Any idea what this line is supposed to do, and why this would stop content from loading and instead show iis 404 error ?

Comment: Which version/build of Sitecore are using?

Comment: Did you just upgrade your .Net solution to use .Net 4 or also upgrade Sitecore? Do you have anything custom code in the Sitecore Pipelines which is overriding the default Sitecore behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the [HttpResponse.TrySkipIisCustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors.aspx) property to True along with setting the Response.StatusCode.